# Catching non-existing parameter inside when block in Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, try-catch

I have a upstream job that triggers downstream jobs under certain conditions.

Since I have a lot of jobs that use same Jenkins File I don't want to insert all parameters to all jobs but handle it by try-catch.

i.e: I want to enter stage 'run' only if parameter.something == false, and in case the parameter does not exist set him to false and than enter the stage.

I thought that MissingPropertyExceptionmpe should handle this but jenkins fails saying it does know the parameter. What am i missing here?

```
stage('Run ') {
        when {
            expression {
                try {
                    params.something == false
                } catch (MissingPropertyExceptionmpe) {
                    echo "something param does not exist"
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Alternatively, consider using short-circuit conditional logic via `params.something != null && params.something == false`. That would also work and be cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: @MattSchuchard That doesn't work, because `params.something` throws, if `something` does not exist. Though it works with `env.something` because this resolves to `null` if `something` does not exist.